# Django LFS 0.10 No default admin user

Tags: python, django, django-lfs

i have installed LFS 0.10 as it said [here](http://lightning-fast-shop.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction/installation.html) but when I go to http://localhost:8000/login I can't login with admin/admin. And auth_user is empty as well.

Does any one know how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a superuser is covered in [the Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial02/#creating-an-admin-user).

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Looking at LFS [installation docs](http://lightning-fast-shop.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction/installation.html), it appears that you can access the `django-admin` utility with `bin/django`, therefore, you can use:

```
bin/django createsuperuser
```

Comment: thanks, but I get this one then Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_manager
ImportError: No module named django.core.management. Seems like python does not see django installed.

Comment: Try `bin/django createsuperuser`.

Comment: Man you are the best! Thanks! Works ike a charm.